# Reactjs some "simple" issue

Tags: reactjs

Why it don't want to work?
Maybe i am doing all wrong?
I such us imported all requare libs,but console shows me weird error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[ÂªÂµï¿š-ï¿œ]/: Range out of order in character class
    at new RegExp ()

```
  <head>
    <title>More Components!</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      #container {
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #FFF;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    function Welcome(props) {
      return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
    }

    const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `charset` into header for `babel`:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  ...
```